# Question about Recoil library on React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, recoiljs

The React Native Cli environment uses the recover library to manage data globally.
I just have the issue that installed `recoil-persist` package and add code `recoilPersist` and set `effects_UNSTABLE` property.
It is normally implemented and operated until data is managed using the `recoil`, but errors occur when using the `recoil-persist` function.
What should i do?

**This is ScreenShot about errors:**

[image]

**this is the code about `recoil` set Code:**

```
import { atom } from 'recoil';
import { recoilPersist } from 'recoil-persist';
import { DiaryType } from '../lib/type';
import { initialDiary } from './initialState';

const {persistAtom} = recoilPersist();

export const diaryState = atom<DiaryType>({
  key: 'diaryState',
  default: initialDiary,
});

export const diaryListState = atom<DiaryType[]>({
  key: 'diaryListState',
  default: [],
  effects_UNSTABLE: [persistAtom],
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming because local storage is a browser property. Since you are using react-native. Local storage will throw an error.

I haven't tested this code, but I believe you can pass local storage from outside. Use the [Async storage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage/).

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';


const { persistAtom } = recoilPersist({
    key: 'recoil-persist',
    storage: AsyncStorage
})
```